# How to create a symlink the desktop way in debian Xfce?

Tags: debian, symlink, xfce

The method of using ctrl + shift and clicking on the item in the file manager does not work.

Is there another method to achieve the creation of a symlink from the desktop?

thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thunar Custom Actions to achieve this. In Thunar, go to Edit > Configure custom actions... > then the plus button.

In the command box, you can put the following:
`ln -s %f ~/Desktop/`

Under the Appearance Conditions tab, use an asterisk in the File Pattern box. Then check everything. Click OK.

Now when you right click a file it will give the option to create a symbolic link. It'll put it on the `~/Desktop`. However, from there you can drag it where you like, and it'll still work.

(FYI, in Debian 10, [there is a bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240403) where your Thunar Custom Actions do not appear on the ~/Desktop for right click.)